# Equals heights of thumbnails with buttons

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code:

```
foreach ($images as $key => $value)
{
$items[$key]['weight'] = $value['fid'].'_'.$value['weight'] ;
$items[$key]['image'] = '<a href="'.image_url($value['uri']).'" data-lightbox="gallery-image_'.$value['fid'].'">'.image_load($value['uri'],array("class"=>"img-thumbnail","thumbs"=>"medium")).'</a>' ;
$items[$key]['title'] = '<span id="title_file_'.$value['fid'].'">'.$value['title'].'</span>' ;

//$cover = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:gallery_cover(\"".$value['fid']."\"); return false;' id='gallery_cover_".$value['fid']."' data-toggle='tooltip' class='data-tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title='Top' id='tooltip1'><span class='btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-".(isset($gallery_cover['value']) && $gallery_cover['value']==$value['fid']?'open':'close')."'></span></a>" ; 
$edit = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:update_file(\"".$value['fid']."\"); return false;' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='tooltip' class='data-tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title='Modifier' id='tooltip1'>Modifier</a>" ; 
$delete = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:delete_added_image(\"".$value['fid'].'_'.$value['weight']."\"); return false;' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='tooltip' class='data-tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title='Supprimer' id='tooltip1'>Supprimer</a>" ; 

$items[$key]['actions'] = $edit." ".$delete ;   


}
foreach($images as $key => $value)
{
if ($key % 4 == 0)
echo "<div class=\"row\">" ; 
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\">" ;
echo "<div class='thumbnail' style='min-height:280px;height:280px;'>".$items[$key]['image'] ."
    <div>
        <h4 style='min-height:50px;'>".$items[$key]['title']."</h4> 
        <p>".$items[$key]['actions']."</p>
    </div>
    </div>" ;
echo "</div>" ;
```

}
the result :

[image: 1]

I want every thumbnais to have a fixed button and title.
Any solution for that ?

Thanks

Comment: May be you need to give fixed width and height for all the images

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: try adding `max-height` also

Comment: is there a way to do it without editing the css file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you should create thumbnails of specific dimensions then this would never be an issue. If however you can't/wont/whatever, then try some css:

```
<style>
  .crop {
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  .crop img {
      width: 300px;
      height: 225px;
      margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
  }
</style>

<div class="crop"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
<div class="crop"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
```

This will resize and crop.

Good luck :)